# Concept of packages in SVN

Tags: svn, migration, package, harvest-scm

We are migrating from [CA Harvest Software Change Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CA_Software_Change_Manager) to svn. In Harvest SCM there is a concept of packages to which we can add a group of files. Similar thing we want to implement in svn. Can I make use of properties for this? If so how?

At any time we should be able to get the history of any package. I have read that properties are not versioned.

Are there any other features I can make use of to implement a package? Package is just a logical entity that holds a group of files. Once unit testing is complete we promote the package to system test and after that to production.

Comment: What did you use to import history from Harvest to SVN? Is it an in-house developed tool?

Answer (score 0):

[Properties](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.props.html) fall into 2 types in svn - those that are versioned (revprops) and those that aren't. The former are the things you'd expect to be versioned, commit author, commit comment etc. The latter are properties that are for 'metadata' about a file - binary or text for example. You wouldn't expect these to be versioned.

Packages... SVN doesn't have the concept of a group of files (unless they're in a directory) that persists across sessions, although it does have the concept of [changelists](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.changelists.html). I'm not familiar enough with Harvest to say whether that would work for you. 
If it doesn't then I think you're going to have to implement packages as branches.

Answer (score 0):

From my brief review of Harvest, a *package* is a set of files you want to change. Subversion doesn't really have the concept -- except where it is sort of built in.

In Subversion, the repository is revisioned and not the individual files in the revision. Therefore, each and every check in changes the repository. This means that all the files you checked in together are in a certain sense a "package". You can simply check in all the files that you've modified, added, and deleted as a single changeset since, by default, Subversion checks in all the changes if you don't specify a list of files.

Because of the way Subversion handles its revisioning, you can easily see which files have been changed in the set.

You can specify individual files and directories to check in, or you can use the *changelist* feature that was introduced in revision 1.5. You can add files to various changelists, and then do operations on those changelists. I haven't seen this feature used all that much.